# Using EE Templates in Custom Controllers Etc

Tags: templates, codeigniter, custom

I've gotten a custom controller set up in my EE install and I'm trying to use an EE template with the custom functions etc I need to use.

```
    <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('This cannot be hit directly.');

    class Example extends EE_Controller {

        function __construct() {

            parent::__construct();

            // get EE
            $this->EE = $this->core->EE;
            // get EE's template library
            $this->EE->TMPL = $this->EE->load->library('template');
        }

        function index() {

            $this->EE->TMPL = new EE_Template();

            //pick our template
            $this->EE->TMPL->run_template_engine('site', 'form');
        }
```

This controller code successfully loads up my EE template, but I haven't had any luck parsing the tags, or sending in values for the tags. What should I do?

I realize I could build modules for custom code etc, but I need to allow for custom controllers for outside Kohana and Symfony code the EE install needs to make friends with.

I tried using the $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables() function that didn't seem to let me swap out the variables either.

For example, my template has code in it like this:

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>{meta_title}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="{meta_description}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{meta_keywords}">
```

Any suggestions?